# Trying to go from Windows 8 to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

First, lets just say I'm not THAT computer savvy, but that hasn't stopped me from messing with my computer. Anyways, was having problems on my computer which came with Windows XP. Since I had access to a Microsoft site due to a college class I was taking, I decided to upgrade my OS and start over. This turned out to be a real challenge because I had also tried to restore my hard drive, and it put Internet Explorer 6 back on, so then I couldn't download the necessary drivers because IE6 was no longer supported, and then I had to install multiple SP for XP, just so I could download the new operating system from the Microsoft site.

Well, I chose Windows 8 because it was "the newest and greatest", right? Wrong. Hate it!

Now I want to try to go back to Windows 7. I have downloaded the Windows 7 OS from the Microsoft site and burnt it onto a disc as an .iso but I can't seem to get it to install. When I try to boot from the disc (as I did with my Windows 8 install) it says that my drive isn't ready. I tried mounting the files to my hard drive and installing that way, but then Windows 8 says that I can't install that "app".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a product key for your edition of Windows 7?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to download a Windows 7 install ISO from Microsoft. They're out there of course, but none from a Microsoft website. I'd double check that you actually have a Windows 7 install DVD burned.

Comment: Burned as an iso? So one file?

Comment: Yes, I have the product key for Windows 7 and I burnt it as an iso file on the DVD, one file. I downloaded it from Microsoft DreamSpark for Academic Institutions. It is labeled as Microsoft Windows 7 Professional. I downloaded both the 32-bit versions and the 64-bit versions, each on a separate DVD.

Comment: @r.tanner.f Yes, you can download a Windows 7 ISO (although not from Microsoft website) [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I was able to accomplish my mission after all. I still had the downloaded file in my download folder, so I mounted it to my hard drive and then opened it up. I then copied these files onto a DVD and was able to install from that. Everything went very smoothly.

Comment: Oh, and just for those you out there who might be concerned. I DO have license to download these programs and install them due to my enrollment in some electronic classes at our local community college. This college has a program set up with Microsoft called DreamSpark where Microsoft gives the students access to this software for setting up computer systems and what not. We have access to operating systems for PCs and networks, as well as developer software and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

Try and create a new ISO, downloading one of these images: http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/

However, these ISO's are of no use without a license (don't split hairs any one, I mean legally); as I can't tell from your post, I'll assume you don't have a W7 license and will therefore have to buy one.

However, your error message says there is a fault with your DVD player; I would try another disc to boot just to see if it works (or not), or use your disc in another machine.